# What does Info!$D$7 mean in Excel?

Tags: excel

What does this mean?

```
Info!$D$7="Metric"
```

Full cell:

```
=IF(Info!$D$7="Metric","m3/h","gpm")
```

No matter what I seem to put into cell D7 (i.e. `Metric`), the value of the cell containing the above formula, does not change.  Searching info on Excel IF statement does not seem to offer help.

Comment: Are you putting it into cell `D7` of the sheet `Info`?

Comment: `Info` is the sheet, `$D$7` is an absolute reference to a cell in that sheet.

Comment: MattC:  no.  MattB:  Yes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Info` is the name of the sheet, `$D$7` is the cell.

The formula is saying that if the value of D7 on the Info sheet is "Metric" then the value of the cell should be m3/h. If it is not, the value of the cell should be gpm.